# SSRS dynamic positioning of tablix

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-formatting, ssrs-tablix

I have four tablix in my report. Tablix 1 always has data. Tablix 2-4 are hidden if they do not have data.

If Tablix 1 has data, Tablix 2 does not have data and Tablix 3-4 have data there is a gap in the report where Tablix 2 would have been.

How can I close the gap when a tablix is hidden because of no data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Select the tablix
2. Go to properties
3. Under "Visibility" set "Hidden" to: "=iif(CountRows(), False, True)"

[image]

Comment: Adding a page break to make the visible tablix move up the page?

Comment: This will hide the tablix if there is no data. However, any other tablix after the hidden one will have a gap.